# Call App Engine Task Queue using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, task-queue

I have created a Push Queue in Google App Engine Task Queue.

Queue Name : default
Task Name : [Auto-generated]

I am trying to call this Task Queue from Google Cloud Functions, wasn't able to find out how this will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Cloud Functions aren't running inside standard env GAE you won't be able to use the task queue. Some possible alternatives to consider are mentioned in [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queue):

> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref).
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

Comment: To be clear, you have to have an App Engine endpoint for Cloud Tasks. So, it would be impossible at this time to create a task in Cloud Tasks without an App Engine Handler, correct? For instance, it wouldn't be possible for a Cloud Task to hit a Cloud Function endpoint?

Comment: Correct, a GAE app in one of certain regions is *required*, see last paragraph above [Use cases](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview#use_cases). The GAE app will actually execute the task.  But I wouldn't call it an `endpoint`: it's unclear if a [GAE endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) is actually needed or you mean something else by endpoint). Without the GAE app there wouldn't be a (functional) Cloud Task, so indeed, there will be no hitting of the CF either :)

Comment: Sorry, the endpoint was a misnomer. That's unfortunate because it doesn't make sense to create an App Engine instance with urls that hit Cloud Functions to just use Cloud Tasks API. Seems like unless they uncouple it using Datastore and Cloud Scheduler as a queueing / execution system makes the most sense.